# SearchWP Results showing html tags

Tags: wordpress

Im using the searchWP plugin in my wordpress site but the results of the keyword is showing html tags in the description. (see picture)

[image: Text]

Is it possible to use a filter to remove those tags from showing up but still show the text without the tags?

The tags are inside the wordpress wysiwyg editor.

Update.

The search-form uses vue.
So if it is possible to trim the html tags from the results using vue i would prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not tested try this.

```
function wpse159789_posts_search( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! preg_match( '/' . $wpdb->posts . '\.post_content LIKE \'%(.+)%\'/', $search, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) ) {
        return $search;
    }
    $search_str = stripslashes( $matches[1][0] );
    // Cater for closed angle pairs embedded in the search string.
    for ( $i = 0, $len = mb_strlen( $search_str ); $i < $len; $i++ ) {
        $q_searches[] = '(<[^>]*>)?' . preg_quote( mb_substr( $search_str, $i, 1 ) );
    }
    $q_search = implode( '', $q_searches );
    $regexs[] = '^[^<]*' . $q_search; // Before any angle bracket.
    $regexs[] = '(<[^>]*>)[^<]*' . $q_search; // After any closed angle bracket pair.
    array_unshift( $regexs, implode( ' OR ', array_fill( 0, count( $regexs ), $wpdb->posts . '.post_content RLIKE %s' ) ) );
    $search_replace = call_user_func_array( array( $wpdb, 'prepare' ), $regexs );
    $search = substr( $search, 0, $matches[0][1] ) . $search_replace . substr( $search, $matches[0][1] + strlen( $matches[0][0] ) );
    return $search;
}
```